# I want to reverse a HTML video after playback is finished?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reverse the video once it is played and play again in reverse.

I have tried using playbackrate as -1. But it is not working , the playback rate value -1 is not supported.

Comment: Make one video out of it? One half forward, the other half reversed and play that?

Answer (score 3):

Playing a video in reverse is non-trivial in general, because many codecs rely on information from previous frames (when playing forward) to decode the current frame; when playing in reverse they'd need to seek around to find the required information.

You'd be better off making a version of the video that is a ping-pong loop by itself (i.e. one copy of the video in forward and one in reverse), and just loop that.